# How to download a file from a sftp server using node js

Tags: node.js, sftp

Is there any way to download files from a sftp server to local folder location using node js.

Tried to get the files using sftp.fastGet

Comment: Q: Is there any way to download files from an SFTP server using NodeJS?  A: Yes, of course.  There are MANY alternatives.  Q: Tried to get the files using sftp.fastGet.  A: OK.  So what went wrong?  Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And please consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" i6f70's reply [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818424/421195).

Comment: The [ssh2-sftp-client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) which you already seem to have tried it, has an example of its usage. What was unclear about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to download files from a server via SFTP. It is a question that can be solved easily by googling. If you google the question, you will find all of them with code examples. The first link on Google is [How to connect to SFTP in Node.js](https://sftptogo.com/blog/node-sftp)

I use [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) module for the job as it is the module that others are based on. My recommendation is to write your own SFTP connector with it. However, you can find a lot of already written implementations on the internet and NPM register, such as [ssh2-sftp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client)
.

A little bit of googling, reading and you can do this! Come back when Google cannot help you, please. Good luck, mate!

Comment: First you are linking to an article which shows the usage of `ssh2-sftp-client`, then you are recommending writing their own connector, then again recommending `ssh2-sftp-client`?

Comment: @gre_gor correct. The link is an example of articles that can be easily found by googling. Then, I recommend writing their own connector to minimise dependencies to the root module. And then I show other variants of implementations in npm modules or whatever. I gave a choice of different variants and ways from which the asking guy should decide what suit him best.

Comment: They already know of `ssh2-sftp-client` as they mentioned `sftp.fastGet`, so it's unclear what their actual problem is. Pointing them again to `ssh2-sftp-client` isn't helpful.